# Quick way to test / verify a partman expert recipe

Tags: preseed

I'm busy writing a preseed config and keep running into issues with my partman expert recipe.

Testing this on a host that has a slow internet connection means 10 - 15 minutes between iteration of testing changes (downloading of setup files for a net boot install).

> Is there a way to run the recipe locally in a `vm` to see what would happen with just that section, instead of all the installation prerequisites to get to that point?

For example, when the network boot gets to the partitioning section, after downloading some of the required tools, the expert recipe is written to `/tmp`.
Ideally, I'm looking for a way to switch to console¸modify the expert recipe in the tmp file, and rerun partman until it passes `/` gives the desired partitioning. Once done, I can update the recipe in the preseed file on the `tftp` for more installs.

Comment: Umm.. yes, like you said: you run it in a vm...

Comment: How do I just run the partman section? If I start off a VM vs a real machine, they both take just as long. Is there a way to create a repo mirror for just the prep stage? and then switch to an official mirror for full package installation?

Comment: I don't understand you... if you want to test your recipe, then you have to feed the recipe to the installer and let it install.  If you don't want to do that on real hardware, you can do it on a vm instead.  You also can speed up the vm a bit by setting the disk emulation to unsafe caching mode.

Comment: I'm using the preseed in a pxeboot environment. I don't want to wait 10 - 15 minutes to download all the required tools to get to the point of partitioning to have it fail, and then modify the preseed config on the tftp server, reboot and wait again to verify fixes. Is there a way to just take the expert recipe and run partman with it manually? e.g. when partman fails, I can switch to console, have the recipe in tmp - I'd like to modify and re-run partman and repeat until the recipe is debugged.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Have added an example of what I'd like to do guntbert.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Have spent too many hours trying to understand why a crypto-lvm recipe doesn't work. Guessing at the combinations or digging into the source code and then guessing, then changing one thing, booting over and over (even in a VM) is a very bad way for me to do software.

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you wanted but you can switch to BusyBox during the installation process, then try fdisk.
But you will have to reboot to load a new recipe, as I don't know how reload the recipe from /tmp.

Installation is on the tty1 and BusyBox tty2 as an example.

From BusyBox you can type : fdisk /dev/sda.
At least you would try. I got the command into a PXE installation, but I just tryed into a VM (iso installation) to check and I can't fdisk...